# How do I specify what version of CUDA libraries my code should be looking for in this container?

Tags: docker, pytorch, nvidia-docker

So my workflow is gonna be a bit wonky, but I'm not permitted to use Docker, so I have Singularity instead.

I'm running some code that is giving me this error:

```
RuntimeError: nvrtc: error: failed to open libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.1.
  Make sure that libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.1 is installed correctly.
nvrtc compilation failed:
```

If more details are needed, I can provide.

I'm operating in a Singularity container built from a docker_hub image I created here: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/elavizadeh/imaginaire_cuda_10.2/builds
(Ignore the fact that the title says cuda_10.2, I'll fix this all up if and when this works.)

Which is based on this dockerfile I created here: https://github.com/EvanLavizadeh/imaginaire-1/blob/master/Dockerfile

In that Dockerfile, I specify a base image "FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.12-py3"
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_20-12.html#rel_20-12

I specifically chose that version of that base image because it claims it has Cuda toolkit 11.1.1 which I am hoping will contain `libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.1`.

But when I spin up my container, cuda reports version 11.0.221:

```
Singularity> nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0
```

Additionally, when I look at the files in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`, I see `libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.0` but not `libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.1`

I believe this is the source of my error but I don't know how to correct it. I either need my code to use `libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.0` instead of `libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.1` or I need my container to build Cuda 11.1 and hopefully generate `libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.0`.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.1.1/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cuda-major-component-versions

Comment: You plainly don't have CUDA 11.1 installed and that is what you must have for this to work

Comment: Hi @talonmies. Yes I know, but if my Dockerfile pulls from here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_20-12.html#rel_20-12 and this claims to have Cuda 11.1, why doesn't cuda 11.1 show up in the container instance? I have tried other releases of the nvidia pytorch base and the cuda version in the container matches the website. Just not that release.

Comment: The Dockerfile your linked to on your github is pulling this: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_21-05.html#rel_21-05 which contains CUDA 11.3, according to the release notes.  So things are extremely messed up and somewhere there is a downgrade going on.